# Robust custom watermark algorithms?

Tags: image-processing, audio-processing, watermarking

I'm doing research on image and audio watermarking, and so far I've read some literature in order to get basic introduction and good initial understanding of this topic. Right now I'm reading book "Digital Watermarking and Steganography" by Cox, et al.

My basic goal is to get know with robust watermarking techniques, especially for medical image marking.

If we look at the types of algorithms, some of the most commonly used (and robust) are Cox, Corvi and Xia algorithm, but all of them rely on watermarks generated as Gauss series of N pseudo-random numbers.

My question is, what if we want to embed custom watermark, like patient information (patient name, date of scan/record, etc.), or to use custom watermark as proof of ownership? Which (robust) algorithms and approaches are used in that case?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what sorta signal would you be embedding these custom watermarks on?  like an ECG signal?

Comment: for now I would just focus on images like x-ray scans, CTs, etc, but also general RGB images custom watermarking..

Comment: would these signals be degraded significantly if the LSB was stripped offa each sample word in the signal?  in audio, we would call that a 6 dB loss of dynamic range.  would a 6 dB loss of signal-to-noise ratio kill you?  is your data that you want watermarked, is that floating point or fixed point?  do you have bits to spare in the sample words?

Comment: also, regarding steganography, do you want these watermarks to hide from people looking for them?  with the intent to remove them upon discovery?  that might be a little more difficult.

Comment: yes, those signals must rely on steganography, for images they should be invisible and for audio they are on low freq unhearable range... I think LSB is a poor approach for this needs, because of huge degradation percentage under different types of attacks (i've tested this). For audio I'm not really sure if 6 db loss of DR would be a bad thing.

Comment: well, making them *"invisible"* is one thing.  making them undiscoverable is another.  putting in a watermark into the LSB of your samples will be invisible as long as your sample words have enough bits.  but keeping the bad guys from stipping the LSB off and putting in random bits (so it looks like a legit signal) or worse, adding their own watermark to the LSB is another issue.

Comment: yes, I agree. Lets say that for now I'm looking for a basic way to embed custom watermark and to be able to successfully compare it (without attacks applied).. can I use like Cox approach with DCT, but instead of gauss random numbers, generate custom 1000 bits watermark constructed from some custom data (transaction id, specific patient data combination, etc.)? have you heard about approaches like that? what results this approach can give?

Comment: this "transparent" watermarking draws a lot from the techniques of transparent quantization, since both introduce little errors into the data.  noise-shaping is one thing to do, but perceptual quantization tricks (which are used in lossy compression) is another.

Comment: what you can do with your 1000 bits of **data** is scramble them with a known scrambling key word.  then the scrambled bits will look noisy and not like data.  then you can replace the LSB with these scrambled data bits, by changing the quantizer from *"round-to-nearest-integer"* to *"round-to-nearest-even"* if the data bit you want is a 0 and  *"round-to-nearest-odd"* if the data bit is 1.  the quantizer can be "noise shaped", but i dunno a good way to do that for image data.  only for audio.

Comment: I will try that approach for audio. Thanks for your replies and time Robert, it was helpful.

Comment: if you do this for audio, there **are** some noise-shaping techniques to steer the quantization noise into higher frequencies where our ears are less sensitive.

Comment: How can I learn more about those techniques? thanks

Comment: there are some old AES papers.  essentially, you model your **total** quantization error as an additive noise source and then negatively feedback that quantization error from the just quantized sample into the following samples **before** quantization.  but i dunno the proper way to do this for images since "time" is not the independent variable and there is no left/right preference as there is for past/future in an audio signal. [here's a good place to begin](https://dsp-nbsphinx.readthedocs.io/en/nbsphinx-experiment/quantization/noise_shaping.html).

Comment: I think I understand. Thank you, I’ll check it.